# How to update layered metadata in RSuite?

Tags: sql, marklogic

**Problem:**

I am able to define `layered metadata` while creating `MO`.

Is there any way to update the existing layered metadata & add new layered metadata elements in the existing `Mo`

Please provide the solution with example.

Also requesting to those who are working in RSuite to create a tag for `RSuite` in stackoverflow. I can't create tags as I don't have enough points.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Dixit,

Please contact RSuite support directly at https://support.rsuitecms.com/. All of our customers and partners have access to support and it is the quickest way to get the answers that you need.